# make: *** No rule to make target .... Stop

Tags: docker, make, c

I failed to compile the below software but ran into an error.

```
wget -c https://sourceforge.net/projects/r8s/files/r8s1.81.tar.gz
tar xvfz r8s1.81.tar.gz
cd r8s1.81/src 
make -f Makefile.linux
ReadNexusFile2.c: In function ‘doSimCommand’:
ReadNexusFile2.c:5385:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("\nBranch evolution simulation:\nseed=%li\n\nrate transition=%f\n",
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/sys/errno.h', needed by 'memory.o'.  Stop.
```

Furthermore, I found a Docker container [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/shkao/r8s) of r8s but our HPC does not allow Docker and it seems I can't find the Dockerfile.

How is it possible to get software compiled?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Besides fixing the compilation error listed there, apparently?

Comment: It would seem that `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` is missing. Solution: Install it. How to install it depends on your Linux flavour.

Comment: Both  `sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev` and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` were available on my ubuntu system installed. Do I need to install anything else to get `r8s` compiled?

Comment: I had to combine solutions from the below sources:
* http://phylobotanist.blogspot.com/2015/02/dated-phylogenies-my-experience-using.html
* https://www.biostars.org/p/386655/#386677

```
> sudo apt install gfortran

> wget -q https://sourceforge.net/projects/r8s/files/r8s1.81.tar.gz \
  && tar -zxvf r8s1.81.tar.gz \
  && cd r8s1.81/src \
  && sed -i 's|/usr/include/sys/errno.h||' Makefile.linux \
  && sed -i 's/continuousML.o //' Makefile.linux \
  && sed -i 's/continuousML.o:/#continuousML.o:/' Makefile.linux \
  && make -f Makefile.linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to combine solutions from the below sources:

- http://phylobotanist.blogspot.com/2015/02/dated-phylogenies-my-experience-using.html
- https://www.biostars.org/p/386655/#386677

```
> sudo apt install gfortran

> wget -q https://sourceforge.net/projects/r8s/files/r8s1.81.tar.gz \
  && tar -zxvf r8s1.81.tar.gz \
  && cd r8s1.81/src \
  && sed -i 's|/usr/include/sys/errno.h||' Makefile.linux \
  && sed -i 's/continuousML.o //' Makefile.linux \
  && sed -i 's/continuousML.o:/#continuousML.o:/' Makefile.linux \
  && make -f Makefile.linux
```